# Proving $\text{div}(\text{curl}(\textbf{F}))=0$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

Assuming the relevant partial derivatives exist and are continuous, $\text{div}(\text{curl}(\textbf{F}))=0$, where $\textbf{F}:\mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ is a vector field. This is easily proved by writing out the components and showing that the mixed partials all cancel (they are equal beause they are continuous).

However, one can also write $\text{div}(\text{curl}(\textbf{F}))=\nabla\cdot(\nabla \times \textbf{F})$, where $\nabla$ is the operator $\left \langle \frac{\partial}{\partial x}, \frac{\partial}{\partial y}, \frac{\partial}{\partial z}\right\rangle$. There is a temptation to say that $\nabla \times \textbf{F}$ is a "vector" perpendicular to $\nabla$, so $\nabla \cdot (\nabla \times \textbf{F})=0$. This is not correct since $\nabla$ is not really a vector. Is there some sense in which this is a correct justification, though? (Treating things purely algebraically?) I don't think it is rigorous enough because it relies on commutativity, i.e. being able to take partial derivatives in any order and get the same answer.

Comment: Commutativity, at the very least, is not an issue here: if partial derivatives of $f$ exist and are continuous, then $\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x \partial y} = \frac{\partial^2f}{\partial y \partial x}$

Comment: I know, but the "purely algebraic" argument of saying that $\nabla \cdot (\nabla \times\textbf{F})$ clearly fails if we do not assume the partials are continuous. This is one reason why I think it is not rigorous enough.

Comment: If it were truly the case that $\nabla$ were somehow orthogonal to $\nabla \times F$, wouldn't we also need $(\nabla \times F)\cdot \nabla =0$ (which BTW, is not generally the case).

Comment: @kccu I wouldn't give too much stock to that failure alone; there are a lot of nice "algebraic" things that happen because we assume that all differential operators will commute, since the functions we consider are "sufficiently nice" for this to occur.

Comment: @Bye_World How do you even make sense of $(\nabla \times \textbf{F})\cdot \nabla$? Dotting with $\nabla$ really only makes sense if it's on the left.

Comment: @kccu It's just an operator derived from the $\nabla$ operator.  For it to equal the $0$ operator, you' d need $[(\nabla \times F)\cdot \nabla]G = 0$ for all $G$.

Comment: @Bye_World So $[(\nabla \times \textbf{F})\cdot \nabla]G=\left(\frac{\partial F_1}{\partial y}- \frac{\partial F_2}{\partial z}\right) \frac{\partial G}{\partial x} - \left(\frac{\partial F_3}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial F_1}{\partial z}\right) \frac{\partial G}{\partial y} + \left(\frac{\partial F_2}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial F_1}{\partial y}\right) \frac{\partial G}{\partial z}$?

Comment: @kccu see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Del#Precautions) for example

Comment: @kccu You got it.

Comment: Thank you. I think I stand by my initial opinion that it is not rigorous enough to just treat $\nabla$ as a vector.